# How to keep a reference cell constant in a linked worksheet when a line is inserted

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, links

I have a workbook with multiple worksheets.  On the main sheet I have links so specific cells on other sheets in the workbook that I want to update automatically when I change the data in that specific cell.  I also want to keep the previous data in the source worksheet so I want to insert a row above that data when I am entering new information.

The links work fine until I do the insert when the formula then changes to the line below where I want the source to be. Pre Windows 10 I was able to doe this (as I recall) by using the $ in my formula but that doesn't work now.  I've searched online and have see suggestions to use INDEX and INDIRECT but Index is not applicable and INDIRECT results in #REF! results.  I just want the link to $A$2 to stay in cell A2 after a new line is inserted.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of the $ sign in Excel has no relation to the operating system and it has not changed with Windows 10.

If you have a link to `='Sheet 2'!$A$2` and you insert a row in Sheet 2 above row 2, then the reference will ajust to `='Sheet 2'!$A$3`, because the cell that is referenced is now in row 3.

If you don't want that behaviour, then you can use

```
=index('Sheet 2'!$A:$A,2)
```

That formula will always return cell A2 on Sheet 2.

The screen capture was taken with Excel 2016 running on Windows 10.

[image]